# What does it mean to be "terminated by a blank"?

Tags: c

"Write a function **int convert ()** that reads a decimal number one character (digit) at a time, terminated by a blank, and returns the value of that number."
Can you help me solve it? I can't understand "terminated by a blank", I usually terminate by an enter.

Comment: It is somehow ambiguous. It _should_ mean, a "space" (or, white-space, to be broad) character should indicate the end of the number.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your teacher means a [Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), however the term *blank* is not used with *C*, rather with Turing Machines.

Whitespace chars are characters used for spacing text, in *C* the common ones are `'\t'`,`'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\f'`, `' '`.

He/She could also mean the null terminator, or `'\0'`, i.e. a character of value 0, but you usually find a newline before the null terminator with common input method.

Whatever he/she means  doesn't matter, as a skilled programmer you already have figured out that the only thing that matters is **telling apart digits from  non digits**.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i'm wrong, but i think a blank is a \0

Comment: You are wrong. \0 is a null. But you should always check for null anyway.

Comment: I thought \0 was the string terminator

Comment: It is. It can appear in an input stream, but it is not very likely. Probably for your exercise you can ignore it, assuming you are reading using getchar().

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether the question meant this...

When you read a character array via gets() function, and press enter the array will be stored with the entered character at the first postion and NULL character **ie:terminated by a blank**. So you can take the first element and print it.